# Do jellyfish have extra energy reserves for emergencies (a "fight or flight" response)?

Tags: marine-biology, energy, stress

My friend is writing a story about jellyfish, and we couldn't find out if jellyfish have the equivalent of a "fight or flight response" or an adrenaline rush. In other words, do they have reserves of energy which lets them do things they wouldn't normally be able to (such as surpass harder obstacles, or move faster even when exhausted) which only get released during emergencies?

I know that jellyfish have a distributed nervous system and no brain, but searching the web for "adrenaline rush" and "fight or flight response" only returned results about how adrenaline/epinephrene is a cure for jellyfish stings rather than speaking about equivalent phenomena for jellyfish themselves.

---

**Side note:** [This comprehensive article](https://www.cell.com/current-biology/fulltext/S0960-9822%2813%2900359-X) in *Current Biology* mentions something called "escape swimming":

> One of the most extensive studies of the neuronal mechanisms of jellyfish behavior has been done on the control of swimming in the hydromedusa *Aglantha digitale*. Atypically for hydromedusae, *Aglantha* has two different swimming modes: slow swimming and escape swimming. Slow swimming is their normal mode, and is mediated by relatively regular and weak propulsion of the bell governed by pacemaker neurons in the nerve rings. Escape swimming produces a much stronger contraction of the bell, and is triggered when one of the giant neurons in the nerve rings (ring giant) is excited by mechanical stimulation of the tentacles

This is more related to neuronal impulses than energy reserves, but perhaps escape swimming bears some relation to energy reserves as well (if that's something that exists for jellyfish)?

Comment: This paper, [Passive energy recapture in jellyfish contributes to propulsive advantage over other metazoans](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3816424/) (pdf is freely available) might be of interest. It includes the following "Medusae can exhibit such low respiration rates due to the large proportion of metabolically inactive tissue during swimming. Jellyfish have low body carbon relative to other swimmers, which results in ≤1% of the body mass represented by muscle. Fish, in comparison, have a body mass that is ≥50% muscle" and much more.

Comment: Interesting! I'm beginning to suspect there's no concept of an energy reserve for them, if their energy use is already so low anyway (not to mention the passive energy recapture described later in the link).

Comment: Search for glycogen and jellyfish (or whatever the proper word for the beasties is). Idly playing I found a paper that implied it was present. I would find it hard to believe they do not build up energy reserves — lack of information does not mean it doesn’t exist. What stimulates breakdown is a different question.